CF A/B Tesing using Lambda@Edge
I'm using Lambda@Edge for CF for A/B testing.
My requirements are as follows:

If there's no cookie abTesting, set cookie abTesting with A or B and also add query param variant with same value.

If there's a cookie abTesting and there's a variant in query, then do nothing, just return request.

If there's a cookie abTesting, but not variant in query, then add variant query param equal to cookie.


So far, it does 1 and 2 fine, but I'm not able to achieve the third. I'm attaching this lambda as Viewer Request, I think that's right? Maybe someone can help, please and thank you!
Attaching the code below, thank you!
const TESTING_SPLIT = 0.5;
const COOKIE_NAME = 'ab_test_variant';

const TestingVariantEnum = {
  VariantA: 'A',
  VariantB: 'B',
};

const getRandomVariant = () =>
  Math.random() > TESTING_SPLIT
    ? TestingVariantEnum.VariantA
    : TestingVariantEnum.VariantB;

const parseCookie = (cookieHeader) => {
  const cookies = cookieHeader.split(';');
  const cookie = cookies.find((cookieValue) =>
    cookieValue.trim().startsWith(COOKIE_NAME)
  );
  if (cookie) {
    const value = cookie.split('=');
    return value[value.length - 1].trim();
  }
  return undefined;
};

const findCookie = (headers) => {
  if (headers.cookie) {
    for (const cookieHeader of headers.cookie) {
      const cookieValue = parseCookie(cookieHeader.value);
      if (cookieValue) {
        return cookieValue;
      }
    }
  }
  return undefined;
};

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const { request } = event.Records[0].cf;
  const { headers, uri, querystring } = request;

  const currentVariant = findCookie(headers);
  const hasQueryVariant = querystring.includes('variant=');

  if (currentVariant && !hasQueryVariant) {
    // If the cookie exists but the variant query parameter does not, append the query parameter
    const newQuerystring = querystring
      ? `${querystring}&variant=${currentVariant}`
      : `variant=${currentVariant}`;
    request.querystring = newQuerystring;
    return request;
  }

  if (currentVariant && hasQueryVariant) {
    // If both the cookie and query parameter exist, do nothing
    return request;
  }

  // If no cookie, generate a new variant and set the cookie
  const variant = getRandomVariant();
  const newQuerystring = querystring
    ? `${querystring}&variant=${variant}`
    : `variant=${variant}`;

  const response = {
    status: '302',
    statusDescription: 'Found',
    headers: {
      'cache-control': [
        {
          key: 'Cache-Control',
          value: 'no-store',
        },
      ],
      'set-cookie': [
        {
          key: 'Set-Cookie',
          value: `${COOKIE_NAME}=${variant}; Path=/; HttpOnly`,
        },
      ],
      location: [
        {
          key: 'Location',
          value: `${uri}?${newQuerystring}`,
        },
      ],
    },
  };

  return response;
};


